# Gradle build error: play-services-ads-base is being requested by various other libraries with different version

Tags: gradle, dependencies, google-play-services

I have checked some other similar errors but none of their solutions has solved mine.

I can not build the project because I'm getting this exact error:

```
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

First of all, I go to the dependency tree, and all uses I see are using version 17.0.0, no one is using 15.0.1. (which causes the conflict)
However, if I open the project dependencies I see different versions between my gradle file and the project list.

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'


implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1"
```

[image: library in project dependencies]

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.2
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4 (*)
```

I have updated all google dependencies to the latest version, but it still does not work..

How can I figure it out which library is using the conflict version, if it's not being shown in the dependency tree?